# Why does this CTE act like a counter?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

The behaviour of  the following query is different from my understanding of CTE, can someone elaborate why this is so?

```
with cte (n) as
(
    select 1
    union all
    select n + 1 from cte where n<10
)
select * from cte
```

I'm expecting the following output:

```
1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10
```

But I'm getting:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Why?

Comment: any reason behind repeating the numbers?

Comment: No real reason, i'm just looking for an explanation why the query output is not what i'm expecting it to be.
It seems I've misunderstood how something in the query works

Comment: why do you expect it to be that output? How are you thinking it works?

Comment: Clearly you query is for the second result.  If you want it to produce the first result, then change your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CTE is basically a re-usable sub-query that can refer to itself, so your final query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT 1
UNION ALL (SELECT 2 
           UNION ALL (SELECT 3 ...
```

Until `n` gets to 10.

Answer (score 3):

The *anchor*, `select 1`, probably doesn't bother you. The result is `1`.

The recursive query, `select n + 1 from cte where n<10`, is executed repeatedly for all *new* rows in the CTE until no new rows are produced (or until the `MaxRecursion` limit is hit).

The first time through the only new row is `1` from the anchor and the result is `2` (`n + 1`). Now there is one new row: `2`. The result: `3`. Lather, rinse, repeat until `n<10` causes no new rows to be generated.