# Logical Processing of Recursive CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I don't understand why the anchor is not called when the recursive member calls the cte.

Why does it go to the latest record (?) in the recursive part instead?

```
WITH Managers AS 
( 
--initialization 
SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, ReportsTo  
FROM Employees 
WHERE ReportsTo IS NULL 
UNION ALL 
--recursive execution 
SELECT e.employeeID,e.LastName, e.ReportsTo 
FROM Employees e INNER JOIN Managers m  
ON e.ReportsTo = m.employeeID 
) 
SELECT * FROM Managers
```

Comment: Please include a dozen rows of sample data into the question, show us what result you expect to get and what result you are getting now.

Comment: If what I got from this post is correct it answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187850/how-does-a-recursive-cte-run-line-by-line.
The latest output of the recursive part is used for input in the recursive part.

Comment: The anchor part is always executed. You say "Why does it go to the latest record?" -- Are you sorting the resulting rows? Do you have an extra filtering condition you are not mentioning?

Comment: This is famous Northwind database and the query produces expected result with CEO (ReportsTo `NULL`) in the first line.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54334978/92546) answer for a trivial rCTE help?

Comment: Just a few days ago there was a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54333927/5089204) with some pretty good answers. In short: Think this more as an **iterative** and not really **recursive** action. Each new step *adds to the result* (similar to a series of `UNION ALL SELECT ...`

Answer (score 1):

This is famous Microsoft sample database `Northwind` (immutable since 1997). The `Emploeees` table demonstrates hierarchical data and usage of recursive CTE (not available in 1997) to access it.

For better understanding / testing / training purpose add an extra column

```
WITH Managers AS 
( 
  --initialization 
  SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, ReportsTo, /*extra column*/ 0 [level]  
  FROM Employees 
  WHERE ReportsTo IS NULL 

  UNION ALL 

  --recursive execution 
  SELECT e.employeeID,e.LastName, e.ReportsTo, [level]+1 
  FROM Employees e 
  INNER JOIN Managers m ON e.ReportsTo = m.employeeID 
) 
SELECT * FROM Managers
```

This is result set.

```
EmployeeID  LastName             ReportsTo   level
----------- -------------------- ----------- -----------
2           Fuller               NULL        0 --anchor call
--now 'Managers' CTE is the anchor (level 0)
1           Davolio              2           1
3           Leverling            2           1
4           Peacock              2           1
5           Buchanan             2           1
8           Callahan             2           1
--now 'Managers' CTE is resultset level 1
6           Suyama               5           2
7           King                 5           2
9           Dodsworth            5           2
```

So the **anchor** executes always, recursive part executes *iff* the anchor returns row(s).